# Error while connecting with QRemote using QODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

Getting this error in SQL Server at a time of connecting to QREMOTE using QODBC

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "QREMOTE" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to QODBC Setup screen --> Advanced tab --> Maximum Field Name Length --> Set " Maximum Field Name Length" to 70.

Also, Please Configure MSDASQL (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers)
[Note: MS SQL Express Edition do not have this setup options!!! ]
The OLE DB provider options for managing linked queries can be set in SQL Server Management Studio. In Object Explorer , right-click the provider name and select Properties for MSDASQL.
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/newimages/QRemoteSQLServer64Bit/image025.png

Dynamic parameter should be checked to allow parameter queries. Level zero only should be checked to allow four part naming to work. Allow InProcess should be checked to help performance.Non transacted updates should be checked if you want to be able to update QuickBooks data. Index as access path should be checked to help performance. Disallow adhoc accesses should be unchecked to allow OPENQUERY to function.
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/newimages/QRemoteSQLServer64Bit/image027.jpg

I would also like to suggest you to refer below mentioned link:
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2458/52/how-to-create-link-server-with-ms-sql-200520082012-64-bit-using-qodbcqremote

If you are still facing issue please create a support ticket at http://support.qodbc.com